# Uncaught TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My react app compiled successfully but the web console is showing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function
    at ./src/db/db.js (db.js:3:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/db/notes.js (notes.js:1:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/components/notecard-list/NoteList.js (MenuBar.js:19:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

This is my db.js which is the file that's telling me has an error:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('<my connection string>', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// Handle database connection events
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  address: String,
  title: String,
  content: String,
  citation: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);
```

Things I've done:

- mongoose reinstallation. made sure it's listed clearly on the package.json - ERROR STILL EXISTS
- imported the package corrected at the db.js file `const mongoose = require('mongoose');` - ERROR STILL EXISTS
- removed and added node_modules and package-lock.json twice - ERROR STILL EXISTS
- made sure my connection string is correct (mongodb compass) - ERROR STILL EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.connect` will not work in a React app running on the browser, just because the version of mongoose made for the browser can only create documents and validate schemas.

According to the documentation found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html):

> Mongoose supports creating schemas and validating documents in the browser. Mongoose's browser library does not support saving documents, queries, populate, discriminators, or any other Mongoose feature other than schemas and validating documents.

For `mongoose.connect` to run, it needs to be run in an environment running node.js.

I hope this helps.